# Dynamically grab filepath from Azure Data Factory Copy Activity Output

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there way I can grab the file path from Azure Data Factory Copy Activity Output. I have another activity in my pipeline that I want to use the output filepath for. I would also add the filepath as a value to parameter as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get filepath from copy activity output.

You can set filepath as parameter, and pass that to dataset.

[image]

dataset of sink:
[image]

Then you can pass this filepath parameter to another activity.